# In Spark dataframe udf, what is the type of function parameters which like struct(col1,col2)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

**Backgroud:**

I have a dataframe which has three columns : `id, x, y`. x,y are Double.

- Firstly, I  `struct (col("x"),col("y"))` to get the coordinate column.
- Then `groupBy(col("id"))` and `agg(collect_list(col("coordinate")))`

So now the df only have two columns: `id ,coordinate`.

I think the datatype of coordinate is `collection.mutable.WrappedArray[(Double,Double)]`. 
  So i passed it to udf. However, the datatype is wrong. I got a Error when run the code. I don't know why. what is the real datatype of struct(col1,col2) ? Or is there another way to get the correct answer easily?

This is code:

```
def getMedianPoint = udf((array1: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[(Double,Double)]) => {  
    var l = (array1.length/2)
    var c = array1(l)
    val x = c._1.asInstanceOf[Double]
    val y = c._2.asInstanceOf[Double]
    (x,y)
})

df.withColumn("coordinate",struct(col("x"),col("y")))
  .groupBy(col("id"))
  .agg(collect_list("coordinate").as("coordinate")
  .withColumn("median",getMedianPoint(col("coordinate")))
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: So the datatype should be _Seq[Row]_ based on Ramesh Maharjan's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > I think the datatype of coordinate is collection.mutable.WrappedArray[(Double,Double)]

**Yes you are absolutely correct to say that**. And *what you've defined as dataTypes in udf function and what you've passed as arguments are correct too*. But **the main issue is the name of keys of the struct column**. As you must have got the following issue

> > cannot resolve 'UDF(coordinate)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires array> type, however, '`coordinate`' is of array> type.;;

The error would go away by simply using `alias` *to rename the struct keys* as

```
df.withColumn("coordinate",struct(col("x").as("_1"),col("y").as("_2")))
  .groupBy(col("id"))
  .agg(collect_list("coordinate").as("coordinate"))
    .withColumn("median",getMedianPoint(col("coordinate")))
```

so that the keyname matches.

**But**

This will give rise to another issue at

```
  var c = array1(l)
```

> > Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to scala.Tuple2

So I would suggest you to change the `udf` function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def getMedianPoint = udf((array1: Seq[Row]) => {
  var l = (array1.length/2)
  (array1(l)(0).asInstanceOf[Double], array1(l)(1).asInstanceOf[Double])
})
```

So that you don't even need to use `alias` as well. So the complete solution would be

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def getMedianPoint = udf((array1: Seq[Row]) => {
  var l = (array1.length/2)
  (array1(l)(0).asInstanceOf[Double], array1(l)(1).asInstanceOf[Double])
})

df.withColumn("coordinate",struct(col("x"),col("y")))
  .groupBy(col("id"))
  .agg(collect_list("coordinate").as("coordinate"))
    .withColumn("median",getMedianPoint(col("coordinate")))
  .show(false)
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Yes, i tried. But it throwed a new exception _Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to scala.Tuple2_

Comment: if the answer helped you please consider accepting it :)

Comment: Sorry,sorry. Just a little busy.It's very useful. Thank you very much!